# Test jumping to the next spec file even though the first spec is not yet finished

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have these two spec file but when I want to execute both of them the browser will open for angula.js web then will switch to angularCal.js and not executing the angular.js at all and I also tried using 'src/test/*.js', it also doesnt work for me. And i tried using suites same problem, and when I executed them separately they work fine.

```
//config
import {Config,browser} from 'protractor';
import{testConfig,platform} from 'protractor-html-reporter-2'

let HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
let jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

let reportsDirectory = './reports';
let dashboardReportDirectory = reportsDirectory + '/dashboardReport';

// An example configuration file
exports.config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
    // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
    // They may include glob patterns.
    //specs: ['src/test/angularCal.js','src/test/angular.js'],
    specs: ['src/test/angularCal.js'],
    //specs: ['*.js'],




    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
    },onPrepare: function () {
      // xml report generated for dashboard
      browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
          consolidateAll: true,
          savePath: reportsDirectory + '/xml',
          filePrefix: 'xmlOutput'
      }));

      var fs = require('fs-extra');
      if (!fs.existsSync(dashboardReportDirectory)) {
          fs.mkdirSync(dashboardReportDirectory);
      }

      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
          specDone: function (result) {
              if (result.status == 'failed') {
                  browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                      var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                      browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                          var stream = fs.createWriteStream(dashboardReportDirectory + '/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
                          stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                          stream.end();
                      });
                  });
              }else if(result.status == 'passed'){
                browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
                  var browserName = caps.get('browserName');

                  browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                      var stream = fs.createWriteStream(dashboardReportDirectory + '/' + browserName + '-' + result.fullName + '.png');
                      stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                      stream.end();
                  });
              });
              }
          }
      });

  },

  onComplete: function () {
      var browserName, browserVersion;
      var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();

      capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
          browserName = caps.get('browserName');
          browserVersion = caps.get('version');
       //let   platform = caps.get('platform');

          var HTMLReport = require('protractor-html-reporter-2');
       let   testConfig = {
              reportTitle: 'Protractor Test Execution Report',
              outputPath: dashboardReportDirectory,
              outputFilename: 'index',
              screenshotPath: './',
              testBrowser: browserName,
              browserVersion: browserVersion,
              modifiedSuiteName: false,
              screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: false,
             // testPlatform: platform
          };
          new HTMLReport().from(reportsDirectory + '/xml/xmlOutput.xml', testConfig);
      });
  },
  };

//angular.js =spec 1

import { browser, by, element } from "protractor";
import { BaseTest } from "../common/BaseTest";
import { angularsite } from "../pageobjects/angular_site";

describe('Angular site', function () {
    let base = new BaseTest()
    //browser.get(base.StartTest(2));
    browser.get("https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview")
    let ang = new angularsite();

    it('Scrolldown', function () {
        ang.scrollSettingSeprate();
    })

    it('Select Text (Alert)', function () {
        ang.autocom(2, 2);
    })


    it('Checkbox', function () {
        ang.checkboxtab();
        ang.clickcheckbox();
    })

    it('DatePicker', function () {
        ang.clickdatetab();
        ang.clickdatemenu();
        ang.clickcurrentdate()
    })


    it('Radiobutton', function () {
        ang.clickradiobuttontab();
        ang.clickradiobutton();
    })


    it('Slider', function () {
        ang.clickslidertab()
        ang.clicksliderop(3, 2, 3, 3)
    })

    it('Switch Alert', function () {
        browser.get("http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/manager/addCust")
        ang.alert(2)

    })



    it('Switch windows', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;// for non angular sites
        browser.get("https://skpatro.github.io/demo/links/")
        ang.switch_windows()

    })



})



angularCal.js = spec2 

import { browser, element, by } from "protractor";
import { BaseTest } from "../common/BaseTest";
import { datatable } from "../pageobjects/table_data";
import { calculator } from "../pageobjects/calculator_page";

describe('Calculator Page', function () {
    let base = new BaseTest()
    let calcu = new calculator();

    beforeEach(function() {
        calcu.clear_num1()
        calcu.clear_num2()
      });

      afterEach(function() {
        calcu.clear_num1()
        calcu.clear_num2()
      });

    browser.get(base.StartTest(1))

    it('Validate Caculator Page Addition feature', function () {
        calcu.enter_num1(2)
        calcu.addition_Operator()
        calcu.enter_num2(3)
        calcu.click_Button();

        calcu.validate_OutPut(4);

    })

    it('Validate Caculator Page Subtraction feature', function () {
        calcu.enter_num1(2)
        calcu.subtract_Operator()
        calcu.enter_num2(3)
        calcu.click_Button();

        calcu.validate_OutPut(5);

    })

    it('Validate Caculator Page Multiplication', function () {
        calcu.enter_num1(11)
        calcu.multi_Operator()
        calcu.enter_num2(12)
        calcu.click_Button();

        calcu.validate_OutPut(4);

    })


    it('Validate Caculator Page Division',function(){
        calcu.enter_num1(2)
        calcu.division_Operator()
        calcu.enter_num2(3)
        calcu.click_Button();

        calcu.validate_OutPut(7);

    })


    it('Validate Caculator Page Modulo',function(){
        calcu.enter_num1(2)
        calcu.modulo_Operator()
        calcu.enter_num2(3)
        calcu.click_Button();

        calcu.validate_OutPut(8);

    })


    it('Get Table data', function () {
        let table = new datatable()
        table.get_dataTable();
    })





})
```

Comment: Please show the code of  the two spec files and your protractor conf.js

Comment: Prepare another two spec files and do very simple thing in each one, like open a url, then click something, then sleep several seconds .   Run these two spec files, if same issue occur,  change your protractor conf file to very simple (remove onPrepare(), onComplete(), addReport ) and run again.      With this method to find out the issue comes from conf file or spec file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code within a describe which is not contained within an `it` or one of the hooks (beforeAll, beforeEach ...) will be executed before **any** tests are run. It it one of the unexpected behaviors of how Jasmine operates.

You are seeing both your URLs being hit immediately because both your browser.gets are running before your tests.

Can you try changing your code to the following

```
describe('Calculator Page', function () {
   beforeAll(function(){
     browser.get(base.StartTest(1))
   })
})
```

Update: Changed structure a little

```
describe('Angular site', function () {
    let base = new BaseTest()
    let ang = new angularsite()

    beforeAll(function(){
       //browser.get(base.StartTest(2));
       browser.get("https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview")
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input working fine now, may add additional question, what to run the Calculator Page then the angular site, what should i do? where do i need the changes?

Comment: @Francis if you want to run those two specs in order then it would be a good idea to create a suite for your tests. It would be similar to what Ansi has posted in his answer but you would have both tests in a single suite like so `suites:{ bothTest:['./src/test/angularCal.js', './src/test/angular.js']}`. This would be run with `protractor conf.js --suite bothTests` With that said I am assuming that you these tests do not depend on one another (they should not)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use suites in your config file :

```
suites: {
angular: './src/test/angular.js',
angularCal: './src/test/angularCal.js'
}
```

Comment: Solved it, thanks for the help, I used your suggestion for my problem above